# How do I link libraries from multiple locations (corresponding to multiple GCC versions)?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, openmp

I am currently trying to use Oracle Linux 6 OS on a SPARC S7 server to run the NPB benchmarks (with OpenMP multithreading support). The OS comes preloaded with `gcc 4.4.7`, which is missing the Niagara 7 optimizations. I downloaded `devtoolset-3` from the Oracle Yum Repository, which has `gcc 4.9.2` installed in `/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin`. However, when I compile the NPB benchmark using the newer gcc, it automatically links to libraries associated with the older `gcc 4.4.7` (located in `/usr/lib`). This caused my program to segfault during execution. I believe that it is because `libgomp 4.4.7` is incompatible with `libgomp 4.9.2`. I have tried several ways of linking to the libraries in the gcc 4.9.2 folder (which is `/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib/gcc`); none of the methods work:

1. `-Xlinker -rpath=lib_location`
2. `-Wl -Bstatic`
3. `-L lib_location`

The closest I got was when using `-Wl -Bstatic ~/libgomp.a` or `-static -L ~/libgomp.a`. It fails to find  libraries such as `libm` that reside in the default gcc lib folder (`usr/lib`).

The actual command used to link is:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/gcc -O3 -fopenmp -mcmodel=medmid -static -L/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib/gcc/sparc64-redhat-linux/4.9.2 -o ../bin/bt.W.x bt.o  initialize.o exact_solution.o exact_rhs.o set_constants.o adi.o  rhs.o x_solve.o y_solve.o solve_subs.o z_solve.o add.o error.o verify.o ../common/print_results.o ../common/c_timers.o ../common/wtime.o -lm -L/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib/gcc/sparc64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/lib/
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/libexec/gcc/sparc64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lm
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/libexec/gcc/sparc64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lrt
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/libexec/gcc/sparc64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/libexec/gcc/sparc64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/ld: cannot find -lc
```

Is there a way I can link just the `libgomp` library from `gcc 4.9.2` while linking the remaining libraries from `gcc 4.4.7`?

Comment: Normally you would set PATH to put the desired directory containing gcc ahead of the system one and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the corresponding /lib64/ (assuming 64 bit gcc).

Comment: Can you elaborate? However, I did try export LD_LIBRARY_PATH and add '/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib/' to path but this doesn't change the use of libraries by linkers. It still uses default libraries which will cause segfault when executing the resulting program.

Answer (score 0):

The `devtoolset` compilers are all using the system `libgcc, libstdc++`, version 4.4.7, and can therefore not compile e.g. c++11.

I guess the `gcc53-c++-5.3.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` will do. Comes with the internal `*/gcc53/lib64{libgcc_s.so**, libgomp.so**, libstdc++}` (version 5.3.0) ... Provides `/usr/bin/{ gcc53, g++53 }`

The package was created a year ago ... well tested, as extra compiler. Download link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNbTBneHgwSzBodFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The original post was for SPARC, however, a platform port of Oracle Linux (not part of upstream RHEL or Fedora).

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do the `-Wl,-Bstatic` thing, make sure to follow it *immediately* by `-Wl,-Bdynamic` to reset to normal after your added library argument. By default, not all system libraries have static versions installed, which is why you get e.g. `cannot find -lc`.

So you can try this as a modification of your workaround:

`-Wl,-Bstatic ~/libgomp.a -Wl,-Bdynamic`

Not pretty, and this question deserves a much better answer (this is still pretty much a hack), but it should get the job done for now.